# Primefaces Autocomplete not passing & to complete method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

We are using Primefaces 2.2.1.
We are using autocomplete to display names from the Database. Some of the names have '&' as part of it. For Instance: Jack & Jill.

When we type & in the autocomplete, the suggestion stops with the character right before '&'.

Names: Jack & Jill, Jackie, Jack & Bill, Jack & Jen.

When typed , "Jack", we get all the above names in the suggestion list.
Whereas when we type  "Jack &", we still get the same list and not narrowing down to 
'Jack & Jill','Jack & Bill', 'Jack & Jen'

When we debug what is being passed to the complete method, we noticed only the characters before '&' are passed. For instance: 'Jack '.

Anything typed after the '&' including the '&' itself is not being passed to the complete method. We found from one of Primefaces forum to use converter, But still of no use. Please advice asap as this is a very critical issue to be solved asap.

Here's the bean code.

```
public List<String> complete(String nameQuery)
{ 
   List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(“Jack & Jill”, “Jackie”, “Jack & Bill”, “Jack & Jen”);
   List<String> suggestedNames= new ArrayList<String>(); 

   for (String name : names) { 
      if (name.toLowerCase().trim().startsWith(nameQuery.toLowerCase().trim())) 
      { 
         suggestedNames.add(name.toUpperCase()); 
      } 
   } 
   return suggestedNames; 
}
```

Xhtml Code

```
<p:autoComplete id="stName" 
   value="#{webBean.personVO.name}" 
   completeMethod="#{webBean.complete}" 
   selectListener="#{webBean.updateSelectedName}" 
   onSelectUpdate="name" 
   maxResults="10">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should post the autocomplete bean code to give more visibility to your question.

Comment: Here's the bean code.

public List<String> complete(String nameQuery) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(“Jack & Jill”, “Jackie”, “Jack & Bill”, “Jack & Jen”);
        List<String> suggestedNames= new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String name : names) {
            if (name.toLowerCase().trim().startsWith(nameQuery.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                suggestedNames.add(name.toUpperCase());
            }
        }
        return suggestedNames;
    }

Comment: Xhtml Code

 <p:autoComplete id="stName"  value="#{webBean.personVO.name}"
                                                completeMethod="#{webBean.complete}"
                                                selectListener="#{webBean.updateSelectedName}"
                                                onSelectUpdate="name"
                                                maxResults="10">

Comment: Should you please edit your post by inserting the code in it, it will help reading it.

Comment: Added the code to the post in more readable format.

Answer (score 0):

Try addinng the onstart attribute to the p:autocomplete tag that calls a javascript function to encode the characters that are being passed as your query to the complete method:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    function escapeTerm(request) {
    request.term = encodeURIComponent(request.term);
    }
    </script>`

`<p:autoComplete id="stName" 
    value="#{webBean.personVO.name}" 
    onstart="escapeTerm(request)"
    completeMethod="#{webBean.complete}" 
    selectListener="#{webBean.updateSelectedName}" 
    onSelectUpdate="name" 
    maxResults="10">`

Answer (score 0):

From: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6378

This solution worked for me adding to to of my JSF page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    PrimeFaces.escapeRegExpOld = PrimeFaces.escapeRegExp;
    PrimeFaces.escapeRegExp = function (c){
        var t = PrimeFaces.escapeRegExpOld(c);
        t = t.replace('&amp;', '&amp;amp;');
        return t;
    }
</script>
```